# jquery replacing string with unknown part

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace

I got this piece of code.

```
    imgsrc = imgsrc.replace('-UNKNOWN_NUMBERx50.jpg','.jpg');
```

So how can I change this to make it replace the value properly, no matter if it's "80x50.jpg" or "120x50.jpg" or anything else?

thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes i tried some regex snippets, i've found, but as im not familiar with regex and certainly not very skilled at js, i couldn't manage to solve it

i found:
/^\d+$/

Comment: Read about [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions), and try (or post your attempts, so we can explain why those attempts failed). Ask again, or reopen the question, when, or if, you get stuck.

Comment: i don't know how to integrate them into my code, i think that's the basic problem. could you give me a hint?

Comment: Use a regular expression. `\d` will match any one number (`0-9`).

Comment: neither imgsrc = imgsrc.replace('-"\d+"x50.jpg','.jpg');
or     imgsrc = imgsrc.replace('-\d+x50.jpg','.jpg'); is working for me

Answer (score 0):

For a regex replace, you need to use the forward slash delimiters like this and escape meta characters if there are any, and in this case, you have the dot `.`:

```
imgsrc = imgsrc.replace(/-\d+x50\.jpg/,'.jpg');
                        ^            ^
```

See if that works now.

`\d+` means 1 or more digits. If you want to have a digit without a leading 0, use something like this instead of `\d+`: `[1-9]\d*`

Comment: thank you very much, it works! almost had it like that now, but i didn't know i had escape the meta characters.

Comment: @Max You need to escape them if you mean the literal. For instance, `.` matches every character if used as is, but matches only a dot if escaped! ^^